# Extensible Mapping design

Tags: oop, design-patterns

We have a scenario here like.

ClassA has some properties and ClassZ has same properties as ClassA and then in the middle we have a mapper which maps properties from ClassZ to ClassA and vice-versa. We are not using Reflections and we do it manually (using classZ.setXXX(classA.getXXX())).

Now suppose we want to extend ClassA to ClassB and add new properties, we also extend ClassZ to ClassY and add similar properties in it. So now we need to have mapping between ClassY and ClassB.

Can someone suggest me a good extensible design pattern to do this. Can this be done using Decorator or may be using Interceptors?

Regards

Comment: why not just subclass a map? i.e. class A extends HashMap<String, Object> {}

Answer (score 0):

Not a design pattern but definitely a tool that can help is [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

It helps with the mapping between two objects. If the property names are similar the mapping will be automatically configured. If you have some exceptions you can define them in one place and reuse it everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. The problem here is not mapping, but some kind of framework or pattern to have extensible mapping.

Answer (score 0):

One approach which I figured out is by using @Decorators (CDI). I define a mapping Decorator which first delegates the call to original mapper and then maps the new fields